# Answers that reference non-open datasets

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that some answers reference non-open datasets (like [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/155/46)). Should these answers be voted down or flagged as low-quality?

Obviously a component of open data is *opening* closed data sets, but I wonder if we should discourage folks linking to non-open sources.

Answer (score 6):

I was just about to ask the same question. My instinct is that it can be helpful to reference non-open sources as a means of describing/discussing the type of data/information being requested (or looked for).

It can also help with pseudo-reverse engineering methods of finding the same data (e.g. in this thread re. [list of non-profits in the US](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16/is-there-a-complete-list-of-all-us-tax-exempt-nonprofits-in-machine-readable-for/19#19) the paid Guidestar use of 990's suggests an 'open' way of looking for similar records).

However, I think it really depends. In some cases (though by no means all), there are paid sources are really just well-organized aggregations of open data.

On the flip side, I don't think paid sources unto themselves would be helpful answers for questions on Open Data.

Comment: Yes. In other words, you wouldn't want paid solutions to become **the** canonical answer to "Open Data" problems (down-vote or remove as 'not useful'). But mentioning them in the context of providing clarity or improving the answer can sometimes be useful. +1

Comment: @RobertCartaino I agree. I would argue that the [general rule from SO meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763) should apply to Open Data as well regarding links as answers.